# how to force to clear interval in Javascript

Tags: javascript

All:

I wonder if there is a way that I can force to clear all the interval counters, for example:

```
/* var counter = */ setInterval(function(){console.log("Tick")}, 1000)
```

But I forget to get the reference ( that `counter` variable, which is a number if printed out in console), I wonder if there is a way I can find what number that Interval is, so I can call `clearInterval`

Comment: No.  You have to keep track of the return value from `setInterval` if you want to clear the interval.

Comment: you need to store the reference to clear the corresponding interval

Comment: Better not forget.

Comment: well... you could monkey patch `window.clearInterval`, but.. let's not do that please

Comment: @Federkun Not gonna do that

Comment: If you want to clear all the intervals, maybe you can try brute force: `for (var i = 1; i < 999999; i++) window.clearInterval(i);`.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i <= Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER; i++) {clearInterval(i);}` will probably do it, but that's **not a good idea at all** for a couple of reasons. You should definitely keep track of the timer ids in a structure/variable.

Comment: Note that in Node.js, `setInterval()` actually returns [an object](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_class_timeout), not [a number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval), so brute forcing would not even be theoretically possible in that case.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thanks for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing you can be sure about the id is that is will be an integer greater than zero. See [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timer-initialisation-steps).

> let handle be a user-agent-defined integer that is greater than zero that will identify the timeout to be set by this call in the list of active timers.

So you can, very inefficiently, try them all:

```
for (let i = 1; i < Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER; i++) {
    clearInterval(i);
}
```

Note that this will take a while (that's a lot of numbers to loop over, although you might assume that the browser will issue them in sequential order and you'll never generate more than a certain number).

Note also that ([See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval)):

> the pool of IDs used by setInterval() and setTimeout() are shared, which means you can technically use clearInterval() and clearTimeout() interchangeably

So this will blat all `setTimeout` calls as well as all `setInterval` calls.

Comment: Probably be faster to `const maxInteger = setInterval(() => {}, 0); for (let i = 1; i <= maxInteger; i++) { clearInterval(i); }`, though as you say, this assumes incrementing sequence which, while a common implementation, isn't guaranteed by the specification.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, one that I don't like, is to monkey patch `setInterval`. Basically, decorate it in a way to store a reference of `setInterval` somewhere else.

```
allIntervals = []
originalSetInterval = window.setInterval
window.setInterval = (...args) => {
    const interval = originalSetInterval(...args)
    allIntervals.push(interval)
    return interval
}

// ...
setInterval(function(){console.log("Tick")}, 1000)
setInterval(function(){console.log("Tick 2")}, 1000)
```

Then it's just a matter of calling all of them to clear them

```
allIntervals.map(window.clearInterval)
```

You may want to override `window.clearInterval` as well, and pop the right value from `allIntervals`.

Comment: Instead of "monkey-patching", just define new functions with different names that do this. Would be much easier to stand behind an answer that doesn't encourage modifying the behavior of global functions.